# Create a custom admin panel

Tags: customization

I'm creating a site that needs to be managed by a client through WordPress' backend. I think the interface may be too complicated for my client. I want to create my own interface from scratch and 'insert' some WordPress function into my custom design. I also don't want to explicitly modify the stock admin page so I can make changes there if needs be.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find anything online to help me with this process other than plugins that don't satisfy my needs. I've been searching for a few days now to no avail.

I want my client to sign in on a custom designed login page and use a custom designed CMS.

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: The goal is not really clear for me. If you will change the areas from the back end, then create a custom role and change the capabilities. For the login give it plugins, solution, tutorials. But if you will change also the design and more, then is a solution with a custom back end, data via Rest API helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty broad but provide your client with a [custom role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) and only allow access to the specific pages you want, whether those are Core or [created by yourself](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page).

That is how I would approach this. You will be working within WordPress and so retain its functionality for yourself but have a truncated interface for your client.